# ssl certificate chain

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, gprs

i have a windows 2008 server and a comodo wildcard cerificate.
i also have a couple of applications running under this certificate.
the application and the certificate work fine and are correctly installed.

i have a gprs module from telit that without ssl works fine but when enabling ssl althougth it works it makes 45seconds in handsake to authenticate the server certification.The delay is surely from the handshake because later on the communication is fast enough.

i am searching quite a while for possible problems. i am leaning to believe that the validation of the certification chain is slow.

how can i reduce this time? do you have any other ideas of possible errors or setting issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is likely happening is that you have not installed the intermediate certificates in the chain on the server. This causes the server not to send those to the client and the client needs to fetch them on its own, which causes the delay. Ensure that all certs in the cert chain, except the root, are present in the local machine Intermediate CAs store.

You can use Wireshark or similar tool to look at the network traffic and see what certificates are being sent from the server to the client. If you could capture the client network traffic, you can see whether my theory above is correct or not and what is causing the delay.

Comment: comodo gives a bundle file that installs the certificate, 3 intermediate certificates and the root certficate. i have used this file. What you said makes sense for the delay so i will look it again. Any other ideas are also welcome!!!

Comment: unfortunately certificate chain is correct! i have checked it again. Any other ideas?

Comment: do you see any other traffic originating from the client? where are the 45 seconds spent? you can look at the timing of the packets sent between the client and server.

Comment: After using Wireshark tool i found out that the delay occurs between the following two packets: 1) "Server Hello, Certificate, Server hello done" and 2) "Client key exchange, Change cipher spec, encrypted handshake message". Is it normal for a gprs device to make 40 sec to create the exchange key using the public key of the server?

Comment: If the device is very underpowered computer, doing the public key operations might take a while. I'm not sure what the processor in the device is and what is expected, but I wouldn't be surprised if this is the bottom line problem.